# Treeview in viewbox wpf

Tags: wpf, treeview, viewbox

Just wondering if it is possible to display treeview in a viewbox.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a very simple answer - yes it is. Not sure what you want to do with it though, so I don't know if it'd be the best approach (this might be something only you can answer).

```
<Viewbox Stretch="None">
    <TreeView>
        <TreeView>
            <TreeViewItem Header="Employee1">
                <TreeViewItem Header="Jesper"/>
                <TreeViewItem Header="Aaberg"/>
                <TreeViewItem Header="12345"/>
            </TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem Header="Employee2">
                <TreeViewItem Header="Dominik"/>
                <TreeViewItem Header="Paiha"/>
                <TreeViewItem Header="98765"/>
            </TreeViewItem>
        </TreeView>

    </TreeView>
</Viewbox>
```